# How to use REST service in snappy-data sql Database

Tags: apache-spark-sql, snappydata

Hi I am start to learn snappy-data documentation version 0.7 for  the purpose of connect to the REST call to access the snappy-data database,I don't know how to use REST service with snappy-data could you tell me anyone how to do that,I searched in the snappy data documentation i can't reach where it's if anyone knows please let me know Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The rest service is based on spark job server. It's rest API is described here - https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/README.md

Is this what you are looking for?
 We will include the appropriate docs before 1.0 GA.

Comment: Yes,I tried this way also, But we can execute the smart connector mode in only spark shell commend But i need to execute in as a spark Job,If you don't mind could you tell me how to Run Smart-connector example as a spark Job executer mode, i searched in Documentation  i am not able to reach there,or else how to run Scala script as a spark Job submit,thank you.

Comment: Other then , there have any Option for directly access the snappy-data database using SQL query, in Java we can use Jdbc to connect the data bases using  query we will get the Output  like that any options are available in snappy-data,using any language if its possible please let me know thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Your scala code can interact with SnappyData in three different modes that are listed here:

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/branch-0.7/docs/deployment.md

The need for each of the mode is explained on the same page.

You can interact with SnappyData using JDBC driver. Alternatively, we have our own sql shell - bin/snappy-shell. You can find the documentation here:

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/branch-0.7/docs/howto.md#howto-jdbc

In fact, our "how to" documents talk elaboratively on how to work with SnappyData.

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/branch-0.7/docs/howto.md

Please go through them and let us know your further questions.

PS: I have given you link to 0.7 documents as you are on that branch.